# D&D3.5e -- Damage Reduction -- DR/Unholy vs DR/Evil

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage-reduction

We've got a party with a Celestial Mystic (Book of Exalted Deeds), and I was reading about his level 9 ability, which grants him DR 10/Unholy. Would this be different from DR/evil, as in it would only be breached by unholy weapons, and not attacks from evil outsiders?

I'm asking this because I haven't seen any monsters or anything that have things like DR/Unholy, Holy, Axiomatic, etc... it's usually just Good/Evil/Lawful/Chaotic. Has anyone seen any material throughout the books like this? My intuition tells me it's a typo and should be DR 10/evil, but the errata doesn't say anything about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don’t repost a question in order to get around a closure. [You’ve already edited your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164865/14878) so wait for it to be reopened.

Answer (score -3):

RAW would say that only weapons with the “unholy” ability would breach the damage reduction.  While monsters do not have “unholy” attacks, their weapons and spells can, much like a monk can have a “holy” Ki strike, as compared to merely a “good” alignment for their fists.

And yes, I know I am answering a question that was previously closed and reposted, but I also know how long and frustrating that wait can be when an answer is wanted and someone is being nit-picky.

Comment: I would suggest deleting this answer and posting it on [the original question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164865/14878) instead of this one.

Comment: That would be nice, but since the other question is closed, and answering in comments is frowned upon, I have chosen to do it this way.

Comment: It has been reopened and answering a question that has been reposted because the original got closed isn't exactly encouraged either since it circumvents the entire reason for question closures.